# Android firebase: pendingDynamicLinkData always null

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-dynamic-links

i'm working on email verification. Email reaches the mailbox and when the user clicks on the link it moves him to the application. When I try to get data from link in getDynamicLinks method, pendingDynamicLinkData is null. But i can get the link from intent.
Link looks like: (https://travellersystems.page.link?link=https://traveller-249409.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/action?apiKey%3DAIzaSyCrwQqjOn5v4BDdkKCZHMmmav1YEzvaq5s%26mode%3DverifyEmail%26oobCode%3D0fQfmM0UAHrdNQbUyntffzFH39GtEODVCiVfnrcD0VUAAAFtIQ0HyQ%26continueUrl%3Dhttps://travellersystems.page.link/verify?email%253Ddaniellegawiec20@gmail.com%26lang%3Dpl&apn=com.client.traveller&amv)

Here I want to get email from the continueURL.

Here i create dynamic link and i'm sending verification email to the user

```
        val url = "https://travellersystems.page.link/verify?email=${FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser?.email}"

        val dynamicLink = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse(url))
            .setDomainUriPrefix("travellersystems.page.link/")
            .setAndroidParameters(DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder("com.client.traveller").build())
            .setIosParameters(
                DynamicLink.IosParameters.Builder("com.example.ios")
                    .setAppStoreId("123456789")
                    .setMinimumVersion("1.0.1")
                    .build())
            .buildDynamicLink()
        Log.e(javaClass.simpleName, dynamicLink.uri.toString())


        val actionCodeSettings = ActionCodeSettings.newBuilder()
            .setUrl(url)
            .setAndroidPackageName("com.client.traveller", true, null)
            .setHandleCodeInApp(true)
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("travellersystems.page.link")
            .build()

        user?.sendEmailVerification(actionCodeSettings)
            ?.addOnCompleteListener{task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful){
                    Log.e(javaClass.simpleName, "sendEmailVerification successful")
                }
                else{
                    Log.e(javaClass.simpleName, task.exception?.localizedMessage)
                }
            }
    }
```

Here i'm trying get some data

```
    private fun getDynamicLinks(){
        FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance()
            .getDynamicLink(intent)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this){ pendingDynamicLinkData ->
                Log.e(javaClass.simpleName, pendingDynamicLinkData?.toString() ?: intent.dataString+"")
                var deepLink: Uri? = null
                if (pendingDynamicLinkData != null){
                    deepLink = pendingDynamicLinkData.link
                    viewModel.setEmailVerified()
                    Dialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.post_email_verification)).show(this.supportFragmentManager, "Weryfikacja e-mail")
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e(javaClass.simpleName, it.message)
            }
    }
```

Activiyt where I have getDynamicLinks in AndroidManifest:

```
        <activity
                android:name=".ui.home.HomeActivity"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.StatusBar.Transparent">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
                <data
                        android:scheme="https"
                        android:host="travellersystems.page.link"
                        />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Can you say what I'm doing wrong?